# что не так с pointcut?

Tags: java, spring-aop

На tutorialspoint приведен такой пример по спрингу:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;  
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning; 

@Aspect
public class Logging {

   /** 
    * This is the method which I would like to execute
    * after a selected method execution.
    */
   @AfterReturning(PointCut = "execution(* com.tutorialspoint.Student.*(..))", 
      returning = "retVal")
   public void afterReturningAdvice(JoinPoint jp, Object retVal){
      System.out.println("Method Signature: "  + jp.getSignature());  
      System.out.println("Returning:" + retVal.toString() );
   }
}
```

Я его копирую полностью, но идея подчеркивает красным PointCut (то что в скобках после Afterreturning. Весь остальной код я тоже просто скопировал (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springaop/springaop_after_returning1.htm). Как это побороть?

Answer (score 0):

poinCut надо было с маленькой буквы написать